# Parse single CSV file with multiple dimension tables

Tags: python, csv, windows-7, python-3.4

I am running Python 3.4 on win 7 64 bits.

Basically I have a CSV file which looks like this:

```
#Begin
#Column1Title;Column2Title;Column3Title;Column4Title
value1;value2;value3;value4
#End
#Begin
#Column1Title;Column2Title;Column3Title;Column4Title;Column5Title;Column6Title
value1;value2;value3;value4;value5;value6
value1;value2;value3;value4;value5;value6
#End
....
```

A single CSV file contains several tables (with different number of columns) delimited by a #begin and #end tags. Each table has a header (column title) and it has nothing to do with other tables of the file, the file has almost 14 000 lines.

I'd like to only determine the position of the `#Begin` and `#end` tags in order to efficiently extract the data within those tags, I'd like to avoid reading the file line by line unless someone indicates me otherwise.

I tried to get around Pandas, installed the 0.15.2 version. So far, I have not been able to produce anything close to what I want with it.

Since the file is long and the next step will be to parse multiple file like this at the same time, I am looking for the most efficient way in terms of time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Computational efficiency is likely less important in most cases than storage access speed. Therefore the best performance speedup will be to only read the file once (not find each `#begin` first then iterate again to process data).

Looping line by line is not in fact terribly inefficient, so an effective approach could be to check each line for a `#begin` tag, then enter a data processing loop for each array that exits when it finds a `#end` tag